# How to partially update a purescript record

Tags: record, purescript

everyone!

I'm a Purescript beginner and have trouble with working on records.

I have one record type:

```
type Employee =
 { firstName :: String
 , lastName :: String
 , address :: String
 , height :: Number
 , weight :: Number
 ...
 }
```

And I want to update just a portion of this record.
Let's say I want to only update height like the following typescript code.

```
let a: Employee = {
 ...a,
 height: 180
}
```

How can I achieve this in Purescript?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Syntax for record update in PureScript is the following:

```
r2 = r1 { x = 42, y = "foo" }
```

Where:

- `r1` is the original record
- `r2` is the new, updated record
- `x` and `y` are record fields (*not necessarily ALL fields*)

The above snippet is equivalent to the following JavaScript code:

```
r2 = { ...r1, x: 42, y: "foo" }
```

Comment: Can you explain to me that to update only x? @Fyodor Soikin

Comment: Just don't include `y`